# meaning of その姿に

Tags: grammar, parsing

I would like to know the meaning of その姿に in the sentence

Context: the character is genuinely impressed by her friend's determination at persisting in a way that seems to be a dead end.

> 素晴らしいわ！その、非効率ながらもロマンを追い求める**その姿に**、私は感動したわ！
>
> Just wonderful ! When I see you
> pursuing something so utterly impractical - and yet so romantic - I'm
> moved to tears !

I've looked into several questions such as

[https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41627/meaning-of-おられる姿](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41627/meaning-of-%E3%81%8A%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E5%A7%BF)

and

[https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9807/whats-the-difference-between-姿すがた-and-形かたち](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9807/whats-the-difference-between-%E5%A7%BF%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%E3%81%9F-and-%E5%BD%A2%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1)

姿 has a lot of meaning such as "the way someone looks", "someone's appearance", so I understand it can mean a lot of things (including working as a nominalizer) but could you give me some info about その姿に ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think rather than the meaning of 姿, what is tripping you up here is the order of the sentence. Everything before this phrase is modifying the noun 姿.

> **非効率ながらもロマンを追い求める**その姿 
> That appearance **of pursuing romance/aspirations no matter how inefficient**.

Which means this clause can be taken out of the sentence, and the independent clause would still make sense. So, if we remove this section, we should get:

> その姿に、私は感動したわ！ 
> At that appearance, I am moved!

The sentence order is reversed to make it more emphatic. We can rearrange this into:

> 私はその姿に感動したわ！ 
> I am moved by that appearance!

Which looks a lot more like a textbook sentence structure.